# Passing userid from Moodle to an external URL

Tags: moodle

I am looking to include URLs in each Moodle course that points to an external site. I'd like to pass the userid and course ID as GET parameters in the URL to the other site. Are there macros or variables in moodle that will be replace with userid or courseid ?

An example - I want to include a URL like

http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi?userid=&courseid=

I am hoping that there is a way to have courseid and user in the URL above be automatically populated by moodle correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the settings in the URL resource, please see: http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=199526#p872867

Comment: Just to notice, it is not possible to pass a fixed string as variable, e.g. it's impossible (moodle 2.1) to use url resource to compose an url like /course/user.php?user=1635&id=20&mode=outline where "outline" is a fixed string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with moodle code: You have the object `$course` and `$user` you just have to write `$course->id` and `$user->id` and that's it!

Comment: in newer moodles the global objects are in capital. $USER and $COURSE